# Why aren't my % Changes additive?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm struggling conceptually with the fact that I have a variable C that is the product of 2 other variables, A and B yet the annual change as a % in C is not the annual change % of A + B.

e.g

[image]

As you can see the total of the 2 is 13.1% not 13.5% - how do I explain this?
Thanks
Jacob

Comment: $(1+x)(1+y)\neq 1+x+y$ but instead is $1+x+y+xy$

Comment: The values for "This Year" and "Last Year" don't have A+B=C either you know.

Comment: Mark, that's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: JB, thanks I changed the + to *.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if $A$ and $B$ both doubled?  Then the percentages for $A$ and $B$ would be $100\%$.  Would you expect $C$ to triple, i.e., increase by $200\%$?  No, because $2\times 2=4$, so there would be a $300\%$ increase.

For very small percentages, adding like that is a good approximation.  But what really happens when you increase by $8.9\%$ is multiplication by $1.089$.  Similarly, increase by $4.3\%$ corresponds to multiplication by $1.043$.  Combining both operations yields multiplication by $(1.089)\times(1.043) =1.135827$, corresponding to an increase of about $13.6\%$.

In general, $(1+a)(1+b) = 1+a+b+ab$.  When $ab$ is small, which happens when both $a$ and $b$ are small, adding $a$ and $b$ gives a good approximation.